# Set NickName for photonplayers unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon

I have a problem seeing the name of the client-side but in my master side names of the player is showing so what I did was like this

```
public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
    PlayersName();
}

private void PlayersName()
{
    if (playerCount == 1)
    {
        playerNames[0].text = "Kingdom Player 1";
        playerNames[1].text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        playerNames[0].text = "Kingdom Player 1";
        playerNames[1].text = "Kingdom Player 2";
    }
}

public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
{
    PlayersName();
}
```

Now it displays in both sides the problem is that it is not optimize well. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: " is that it is not optimize well" what do you mean by this? Can you be more specific?

Comment: update the post with proper format/alignment and made few changes in content.

Answer (score 1):

In the photon, you have to check your current room players.
  You have too little change in your code. you can't use directly player count. after change, this code is working properly.

```
public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
    PlayersName();
}

public void PlayersName()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 1)
    {
        playerNames[0].text = "Kingdom Player 1";
        playerNames[1].text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        playerNames[0].text = "Kingdom Player 1";
        playerNames[1].text = "Kingdom Player 2";
    }
}
public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
{
    PlayersName();
}
```

Comment: the problem here is that when i left the room for example i am the player1 and you are the player2 then player1 is still displayed but the player2 is the one who left and its not right. right?

Comment: In that case, you have to manage the player by the master client or player list.

Comment: Could you give me an example please

Comment: Sure I'll give you another answer you can try it. In my code, it's working properly.